# Showing only one feed from different URLs

Tags: views, feeds

I am using the Drupal 7 core module feed aggregator to list rss feeds from different websites.
I am able to show 5 feeds in a block provided by the module itself as well as using views too(aggregator term type).
I want to show only one recent feed from different URLs which are provided by me in the aggregator module config. Right now it is showing 5 feeds from only two URLs.
It should come as:

*Most recent Feed from 1st URL

*Most recent Feed from 2nd URL

*Most recent Feed from 3rd URL

*Most recent Feed from 4th URL

*Most recent Feed from 5th URL

Can anyone please tell me how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to create an attachment display for each feed which selects just the most recent feed and combine them into a block display.